# How to generate Views using databasefirst and entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio, ef-database-first

I've been given a Visual Studio solution to get up and running again for development. The project uses Entity Framework database first. When I generate model from database, the sql wants to convert all of the views into tables. I know views should be avoided with EF, but what is the best way to correct this issue given that the developer no longer works for us?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that there is not a way to recreate view entities in your edmx back into actual sql server database views. What needs to happen is that you would generate the sql from the model and run that sql in sql server management studio query analyzer. Delete the tables created that should have been views and figure out what query to write to recreate the views in sql server as they should be. Once that's done, the views in your model should be fine and update there after when running "Update from Database".

Say you have two tables - Categories and Products. You want to create a view called ProductsWithCategoryName. When you do update from database and this view gets added to your EDMX file, viewing the XML shows the following:

```
    <EntitySet Name="ProductsWithCategoryName" EntityType="NorthwindModel.Store.ProductsWithCategoryName" store:Type="Views" store:Schema="dbo" store:Name="ProductsWithCategoryName">
  <DefiningQuery>
      SELECT
      [ProductsWithCategoryName].[ProductID] AS [ProductID],
      [ProductsWithCategoryName].[ProductName] AS [ProductName],
      [ProductsWithCategoryName].[UnitsInStock] AS [UnitsInStock],
      [ProductsWithCategoryName].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName]
      FROM [dbo].[ProductsWithCategoryName] AS [ProductsWithCategoryName]
  </DefiningQuery>
</EntitySet>
```

Problem with the above is that the defining query is NOT the query that creates that view. For you to get the proper defining query you must actually edit the EDMX file by hand adding the proper query to it as follows:

```
<EntitySet Name="ProductsWithCategoryName" EntityType="NorthwindModel.Store.ProductsWithCategoryName" store:Type="Views" store:Schema="dbo" store:Name="ProductsWithCategoryName">
  <DefiningQuery>
      SELECT        dbo.Products.ProductID, dbo.Products.ProductName, dbo.Products.UnitsInStock, dbo.Categories.CategoryName
      FROM            dbo.Categories INNER JOIN
      dbo.Products ON dbo.Categories.CategoryID = dbo.Products.CategoryID
  </DefiningQuery>
</EntitySet>
```

This still will not give you the expected outcome of a proper sql view getting created. Basically EF when going from the conceptual to the database only produces an table per entity and views are simply seen as another entity.

Comment: Also note that if the previous developer did this and were to run "Update from Database" again, these changes would be lost. I'm not sure what the right approach would be to saving your view queries.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using views with Entity Framework.  I assume you mean to say when you update from database it is trying to convert the views to model objects.  This is totally fine.  often times you are required to specify the primary key for the view.  By default Entity Framework will try to use every non null property as the key.  in the context menu for each property you can toggle this.

Are you getting an error?

Comment: It is a database first use of Entity Framework and the issue I have is when you try to create a database from the model contained withing the Visual Studio solution. You can of course do this and it will behave just as if you were doing model first (which btw turns into database first after you build you db for the first time). Problem is, model first type of approach doesn't work when the model has views that were added from a database. Views do not get created as views. They will get reversed into tables in your db which is not what I want.

Comment: I am a little confused.  If you are doing database first views work great and are easy to implement.  It usually complains about a primary key.  I don't know what issue you are having.  What messages are being returned when you update from database?

Comment: I think what you are missing here is the fact that I no longer have the database. You cannot have views that are in your EF edmx file correctly created back into sql server views IF you no longer have the database. EF will create them as tables in your database. So I am not "Updating from Database" Again this is a situation where the database no longer exists.

Comment: Basically you cannot round trip in EF when using database first.

Comment: You can find the contents of the lost view inside the xml of the EDMX.  It should be in a define query tag.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: See my answer post addition.